# Excel formula to lookup formula 1 cell below & 3 cells to the right of reference

Tags: excel

Just need a formula that I can use on a different sheet to look up the value in A1 (John) & return the value in C2 (33). Thank yall.

[image: Excel sheet]

Comment: My picture aint showing up, but hopefully you all catch my drift. Kinda looking for a vlookup thing, but something that will give me the cell contents of 1 cell under & 3 to the right of my lookup value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your formula:

- `A6` is the lookup (John or Peter)
- `A1:A4` is the range where we look for the lookup (John or Peter)
- `A1:C4` is the range where we look for the value (33 or 7)

  =INDEX(A1:C4,MATCH(A6,A1:A4,0)+1,3)

Comment: The Vlookup formula was wrong.  This one using the match is better, but it also gives 7 for "Qwonk".

Comment: @Penfold You're right! I updated my answer. Should be ok now ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `=OFFSET(A1; MATCH("Peter";A1:A6;0); 2)`

The `MATCH` finds the right row number, and then the `OFFSET` uses that row number and 2 columns to the right.

Comment: I am giving you an upvote, Penfold. I was not clear in my question. If you are on the same page, you can use your formula and it works great. Thanks.

Comment: Weird. So you accepted the other answer instead, which was given later, was wrong, was edited to still be wrong and then edited to be more or less the same as this answer, which was given first? :/